# Trying to remove duplicates from JSON array with array_unique and array_values

Tags: php, array-merge, array-unique

I was following this but it still doesn't work for me: [How to remove duplicate data of JSON object using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34986948/how-to-remove-duplicate-data-of-json-object-using-php)

In my `PHP` file I have 3 `JSON arrays`:

```
{"results":[{"cat_id":2,"cat_name":"veterinarian"},{"cat_id":3,"cat_name":"electrician"},
{"cat_id":4,"cat_name":"dentist"}]}
```

Array2:

```
 {"results":[{"cat_id":"8","cat_name":"dental hygienist"},{"cat_id":"5","cat_name":"stocktaker"},
{"cat_id":"9","cat_name":"builder"}]}
```

Array3:

```
{"results":[{"cat_id":4,"cat_name":"dentist"},{"cat_id":5,"cat_name":"stocktaker"},
{"cat_id":3,"cat_name":"electrician"}]}
```

I want to merge these and remove duplicates. I'm trying like this:

```
//this works good, all merged into one
$array1AndArray2AndArray3 = array_merge_recursive($array1,$array2, $array3);

//now I want to remove duplicates:
$uniqueArray = array_values(array_unique($array1AndArray2AndArray3, SORT_REGULAR));

echo "Unique array is " . json_encode($uniqueArray);
```

But I am getting:

```
Unique array is [[{"cat_id":2,"cat_name":"veterinarian"},{"cat_id":3,"cat_name":"electrician"},
{"cat_id":4,"cat_name":"dentist"},
{"cat_id":"8","cat_name":"dental hygienist"},{"cat_id":"5","cat_name":"stocktaker"},
{"cat_id":"9","cat_name":"builder"},
{"cat_id":4,"cat_name":"dentist"},
{"cat_id":5,"cat_name":"stocktaker"},
{"cat_id":3,"cat_name":"electrician"}]]
```

As you can see, duplicates are not removed, and there's extra `[]` and `"results"` is missing.

Can you tell me how I can fix this, or another way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below solution

```
$array1 = '{"results":[{"cat_id":2,"cat_name":"veterinarian"},{"cat_id":3,"cat_name":"electrician"},{"cat_id":4,"cat_name":"dentist"}]}';
$array2 = '{"results":[{"cat_id":"8","cat_name":"dental hygienist"},{"cat_id":"5","cat_name":"stocktaker"},{"cat_id":"9","cat_name":"builder"}]}';
$array3 = '{"results":[{"cat_id":4,"cat_name":"dentist"},{"cat_id":5,"cat_name":"stocktaker"},{"cat_id":3,"cat_name":"electrician"}]}';

$array1 =  json_decode($array1, TRUE);
$array2 =  json_decode($array2, TRUE);
$array3 =  json_decode($array3, TRUE);

$array4 = array_merge_recursive($array1['results'], $array2['results'], $array3['results']);

$uniqueArray['results'] = array_values(array_unique($array4, SORT_REGULAR));
```

Comment: Hehe looks familiar, @CHarris, maybe add into your post that the JSON arrays are converted for display and/or are stored as PHP arrays to begin with

Comment: @TCooper - I had updated your code with that but you may be removed that answer :)

Comment: yeah, didn't want to clutter the page with useless info (my answer). Sorry to hijack your answer Jaydp - I recently answered similarly

Comment: Good stuff, thanks - just made a small edit to get the 'results' part.